# How to capture both lookahead lookbehind regex python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Here is a string:

```
str = "Academy \nADDITIONAL\nAwards and Recognition: Greek Man of the Year 2011 Stanford PanHellenic Community, American Delegate 2010 Global\nEngagement Summit, Honorary Speaker 2010 SELA Convention, Semi-Finalist 2010 Strauss Foundation Scholarship Program\nComputer Skills: Competency: MATLAB, MySQL/PHP, JavaScript, Objective-C, Git Proficiency: Adobe Creative Suite, Excel\n(highly advanced), PowerPoint, HTML5/CSS3\nLanguages: Fluent English, Advanced Spanish\n\x0c"
```

I'd like to capture from "ADDTIONAL" to "Languages" so I wrote this regex:

```
regex = r'(?<=\n(ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)[\s\S]+?(?=\n(Languages|LANGUAGES)\n*)'
```

However it only catches everything in between `([\s\S]+)`. It does NOT catch `ADDTIONAL` & `Languages`. What am I missing here?

Comment: The whole point of lookahead and lookbehind is that they're **not** included in the match. It just requires that they be there in the string.

Comment: Use normal capturing groups if you want to include them.

Comment: Or use non-capturing groups if you want to include them but not as separate captures.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood well what you need to capture, is it this "***ADDITIONAL Awards: 2010 Global Engagement Summit, Languages***" ?

Comment: instead, you can use `(?=(ADDITIONAL|Additional))([\s\S]+?)(?<=(Languages|LANGUAGES))` and the `([\s\S]+?)` will itself contain all data you want

Comment: @rock321987 Thank you! Yes, yours works. I updated the string that I need to match. I need '\n' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is

```
regex = r'(?<=\n(ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)[\s\S]+?(?=\n(Languages|LANGUAGES)\n*)'
```

and your string is

```
Academy \nADDITIONAL\nAwards and Recognition: ... \nLanguages:
                     ^^                          ^^
                     ||                          ||
Match Position:-(?<=\n(ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)(?=\n(Languages|LANGUAGES)\n*)
```

So `[\s\S]+?` will contain the contents in between these two positions excluding `ADDITIONAL` and `LANGUAGES`.

You just have to find the starting position of `ADDITIONAL` and ending position of `LANGUAGES`. This can be done using the following regex

```
(?=\n(ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)([\s\S]+?)(?<=\n(Languages|LANGUAGES)\b)
```

Further, if you want `[\s\S]+?` only to capture all contents, then you can use non capturing groups for `Additional` and `Languages`

```
(?=\n(?:ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)[\s\S]+?(?<=\n(?:Languages|LANGUAGES)\b)

Academy \nADDITIONAL\nAwards and Recognition: ... \nLanguages:
        ^^                                                  ^^
        ||                                                  ||
(?=\n(ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)             (?<=\n(Languages|LANGUAGES))
```

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'(?=\n(?:ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n)[\s\S]+?(?<=\n(?:Languages|LANGUAGES)\b)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "Academy \nADDITIONAL\nAwards and Recognition: Greek Man of the Year 2011 Stanford PanHellenic Community, American Delegate 2010 Global\nEngagement Summit, Honorary Speaker 2010 SELA Convention, Semi-Finalist 2010 Strauss Foundation Scholarship Program\nComputer Skills: Competency: MATLAB, MySQL/PHP, JavaScript, Objective-C, Git Proficiency: Adobe Creative Suite, Excel\n(highly advanced), PowerPoint, HTML5/CSS3\nLanguages: Fluent English, Advanced Spanish\n\x0c"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/2SgTMc)**

Comment: Best Answer among all!

Comment: @DDDrupal thanks, but i will say this could have been done without look arounds

Answer (score 1):

It is being captured but it's not part of capture group 0 because group 0
contains only the *consumed* match, i.e. the match that moved the current
position.

Assertions don't move the position, so if you capture inside an assertion
it does not become part of the match.

However if the assertion were followed by some sub-expression that consumed
the ones referenced in the assertion, it would become part of the overall match.

Your current regex will not match your string. To match the string you have
to remove the newlines `\n` references.

```
 (?<=
      ( ADDITIONAL | Additional )   # (1)
 )
 [\s\S]+? 
 (?=
      ( Languages | LANGUAGES )     # (2)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include them in the match, don't put them in lookarounds, since the purpose of those is to test for surrounding text without including it in the match result. Use ordinary non-capturing groups if you just need alternation.

```
regex = r'\n(?:ADDITIONAL|Additional)\n[\s\S]+?\n(?:Languages|LANGUAGES)\n*'
```

BTW, your regexp requires newlines around `ADDITIONAL` and `Languages`, but there aren't any in your string.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the answer. I tried yours but it doesn't catch. The text I'm trying to match is:  "Academy \nADDITIONAL\nAwards and Recognition: Greek Man of the Year 2011 Stanford PanHellenic Community, American Delegate 2010 Global\nEngagement Summit, Honorary Speaker 2010 SELA Convention, Semi-Finalist 2010 Strauss Foundation Scholarship Program\nComputer Skills: Competency: MATLAB, MySQL/PHP, JavaScript, Objective-C, Git Proficiency: Adobe Creative Suite, Excel\n(highly advanced), PowerPoint, HTML5/CSS3\nLanguages: Fluent English, Advanced Spanish\n\x0c"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<=ADDITIONAL\s).*?(?=\sLanguages)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ2jN2/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?<=…)`: Positive lookbehind [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wU2aD6/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`(?=…)`: Positive lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cV6wG7/1)

Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=ADDITIONAL\s).*?(?=\sLanguages)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"the companys direction ADDITIONAL Awards: 2010 Global Engagement Summit, Languages: Fluent Japanese"

g = re.findall(p, test_str)
print g //[u'Awards: 2010 Global Engagement Summit,']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just capture  content inclusive of `ADDITIONAL` and `LANGUAGES`, use simple regex like this.

```
\b(ADDITIONAL .* Languages)\b
```

Make sure you are including re.IGNORECASE flag when using in solution.

See demo at [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/sZ0hV1/1)

Comment: Should be (ADDITIONAL|Additional)  not all small cap.

Comment: Not sure which output do you want? https://regex101.com/r/cB7qQ0/1 or https://regex101.com/r/oK2xT5/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're complicating something easy, i.e.:

```
match = re.search("(ADDITIONAL.*?Languages)", subject, re.MULTILINE)
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

```
(ADDITIONAL.*?Languages)


Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(ADDITIONAL.*?Languages)»
   Match the character string “ADDITIONAL” literally (case sensitive) «ADDITIONAL»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character string “Languages” literally (case sensitive) «Languages»
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ4cB8/1)